# Popout window after clicking a link

Tags: css

Like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8egRC.png

How can I do it? I've looked up online and only managed to create a popout window with pure CSS but I wasn't able to click around which is something that I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You can implements your css with focus

```
a.button {
    background: #000;
    display:block
}

a.button div {
    display:none;
}

a.button:focus div {
    display:block
}
```

Only for this example:

```
<a class="button" href="#">Clickme
    <div>Content hidden</div>
<a>
```

Last part, Click on link, then its will to show div.
You can add more style to div, such as position absolute, background etc.